# Is jQuery needed for PhoneGap?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cordova

I am new to Phonegap to develop native Applications. I cant see any jQuery files under WWW folder. Why should i download it?

Is it possible to bring UITabBar, UITableView everything through Phonegap and javascript without jQuery? What is senchaTouch, what is the purpose of it? Anybody can give clear direction?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not required to make apps with PhoneGap.  However, if you would like to, you can use jQuery in your apps if you wish (jQuery just uses Javascript itself).

UITabBar and UITableView are native iOS controls.  PhoneGap does not provide a way for you to use those at the moment.  But if you take a look at the [PhoneGap roadmap](http://www.phonegap.com/about/roadmap), you will see a bullet point marked "Native Controls" - so don't give up hope!

Comment: DId you check this http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494801/iPhone%3A%20UIControls%20%28TabBar%29    ..it says we can bring UItabbar through phonegap?

Comment: Well, I do see that big note at the top "UIControls are now officially dead as of 0.9.2 and will not be supported (it never really was officially part of the core)."  However, the link to https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/NativeControls/ looks promising.

Comment: I am using Phonegap 1.0.0. is it possible?